# How to update a ipywidget called from the callback of an ipywidget?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I am having troubles understanding the functioning of `update` on an IPython `display`.

It seems that to be updated the widget needs to be instantiated at the top level and cannot be instantiated from the callback of an ipywidget.

Here is a non-working exampled of an IPython `display` called by a ipywidget `Button`:

```py
import functools
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import random

def foo(b):
    label = display('Initial text', display_id = True)

    def on_button_click(b, label):
        label.update('New number {}'.format(random.random()))

    button = widgets.Button(description="New number")
    display(button)           
    button.on_click(functools.partial(on_button_click, label=label))


button = widgets.Button(description="Button")
button.on_click(foo)
display(button)
```

[image: Binder]

In this example clicking on <kbd>Button</kbd> displays a text `label` and a new button (<kbd>New number</kbd>).
However, clicking on <kbd>New number</kbd> does not update the text `label`.

Calling `foo(0)` directly works correctly. When the <kbd>New number</kbd> button is clicked, the text `label` is updated.

Is something wrong with the code example? Why can't an ipywidget be updated if it is instantiated from the callback of another widget?

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this issue before and it can be due with where the output is routed when using `display`. I can get the desired behaviour by wrapping your function with a context manager Output widget.

For anything more complex I would consider building a class deriving from HBox, containing an Output widget and various buttons.

```py
import functools
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import random

out = widgets.Output()


def foo(b):
    with out:
        label = display('Initial text', display_id = True)

        def on_button_click(b, label):
            label.update('New number {}'.format(random.random()))

        button = widgets.Button(description="New number")
        display(button)           
        button.on_click(functools.partial(on_button_click, label=label))


button = widgets.Button(description="Button")
button.on_click(foo)
display(button)
display(out)
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. In practice I was aware of this solution and I am looking for an explanation of the `display` mechanism. If you have any ideas on how to reformulate the question to be more generic do feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean to achieve is this:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import random

text = widgets.Text('Initial text')
out = widgets.HBox([text])

def foo(b):
  text.value = 'New number {}'.format(random.random())
  # alternatively: out.children = [widgets.Text('New number {}'.format(random.random()))]

button = widgets.Button(description="Button")
button.on_click(foo)
display(button)
display(out)
```